# Web page not loading with PHP-MySQL code while outputting JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using the code below to get information from a database and make it into JSON (it may be wrong).

Unfortunately it won't load in my web browser, it just says it's loading but it doesn't finish. Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$array = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
$array[] = $row; 
$postID =     $row['id']; 
while ($ra = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE postID = '$postID'"))) { 
$array['comments'] = $ra; 
} 
while ($rd = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Likes WHERE postID = '$postID'"))) { 
$array['likes'] = $rd;
 } 
} 
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing `mysql_query` in the infinite loop: 
  on each iteration you query the database, and fetch the first row. Change it to

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE postID = '$postID'");
if (!$res)
{
   // handle error
}
while ($ra = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{
 ....
}
```

And the same for your second query.